# Query MS Excel Online Spreadsheet and Calculate Averages

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering if the MS Excel Online has a capability to query the data like you would query with SQL? For example

```
"SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE date>today()-7 AND date<today() AND `some other condition`"
```

I'm trying to make some data aggregations in one spreadsheet and show it in the other, but don't have enough experience with Excel, not sure if and how this can be achieved.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried? What is the result?

Comment: Sorry, but tried what? I'm not sure if that's possible. Where do I enter such a query in MS Excel Online?

Comment: You could look into power query, or even AVERAGEIFS formulas.

Comment: Sounds like you want `FILTER()`

Comment: We expect people to "do their homework" here. Not know the answer to their question, but to have done research and tried things. Please show us the research you've done and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Isolated I've figured out that this could be achieved using AVERAGIFS as follows:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Table1[Title];Table1[Department];"Sales";Table1[Start time];">="&$F3;Table1[Start time];"<="&$G3 + 1)
```

Where the cells F3 and G3 contain the start and end dates respectively.